# mod operator on floating point values in c. This is showing error "illegal use of floating point"

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  float n, r;
  printf("\n enter a number");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  r=n%10;
  n/=10;
  printf("%d %d",n, r );
  getch();
}
```

This code is showing error while compiling.
I want to know: can we perform mod operation on floating point values?

Comment: Please read the manual for `scanf`, including what the `%d` format specifier does, and what type of arguments are expected when you use it.

Comment: *can we perform mode operation on floating point values*: **No**.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mod` operator instead of "mode " operator.

Comment: `float n, r;` --> `int n, r;`

Comment: "can we perform mod operation on floating point values?"  not quite.  C has `fmodf()` which is the same as the Euclidean "mod operation" for positive values.  In C `fmodf()` does a "remainder" which differs from "mod" when an operand is negative.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't use `%` on float

Use `fmod` function instead 
Referenced here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/

Or `fmodf` 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod

`r = fmod (n, 10)`

You need to `#include <math.h>`  to use this function

Also, you should do `scanf(%f, &n)` to read in the `float`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
  float n, r;
  printf("\n enter a number");
  scanf("%f", &n);
  r=fmod(n,10.0);
  //r = fmodf(n, 10.0); thansk to chux
  n /= 10;
  printf("%f %f", n, r );
}
```

Comment: Can you also mention the error that @NateEldredge alluded to?

Comment: @WeatherVane sure

Comment: `fmodf()` makes more sense for `float` arguments.

Comment: @chux it does, but c would implicitly convert 10 to 10.0 in this case

Comment: True, yet with `fmod()`, the `n` is converted from `float` to`double`. Then `fmod()` computes the `double` remainder and then `r = ` converts that `double` remainder to `float`.  `fmodf()` is likely faster than `fmod()` and code avoids the 2 conversions of `float` to `double` and `double` to `float`.

Comment: @chux it is a great point, I would keep this in mind in my future

Comment: Most `<math.h>` functions have `float` and `long double` versions.

Comment: @chux, seems in `c++98` and the following versions, these function has actually been combined, into `fmod()` with multiple overloaded versions?

Comment: This question/answer is `C`, my comments reflect that.  Other languages like `c++98`, as well as Java, C# and a new [JM-C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157511/james-maa) may do other things.